# Transfer map<string, pair> to vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

So I have this map m

```
typedef pair<int,int>p;
map<string, p> m;
```

It holds all of the words in a text file, and the first int in the pair is the frequency of the word and the second is the position of its first character in the text file. These are all calculated and the map works fine.

HOWEVER

I need to print these words out, sorted by frequency in descending order. I need the position counter because if two words have the same frequency, the one that comes first in the file should come first in the list.

How do I transfer this map into a vector?

I tried

```
   copy(m.begin(), m.end(), back_inserter(wordList));
```

to no avail

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Okay So I've changed wordList to `vector<pair<string, pair<int, int> > >`
And my copy now works. Thank you guys

Comment: What is `wordlist`?  Do you get a compile error, or runtime problems?  What errors do you get?  We can guess but it'd be better if you told us.

Comment: It's already sorted lexicographically in the map, moving it to a vector won't magically alter the ordering.

Comment: That copy will work if `wordList` is a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::pair<int, int> > >`.   Otherwise you need do some work to map the data in the map into a form that can be stored to the vector.

Comment: Do you really need a vector here, I think it would work a lot better for your proposed issue to construct a std::multimap of frequencies to words.

Comment: Apologies. wordList is the vector I am currently trying to use. It is vector <string, p>. It gives me 100s of errors all about pointers and different things, I think im mis-using these containers. Also I need it sorted by number, not alphabetically

Comment: @Peter That should be `std::vector<std::pair<const std::string, std::pair<int, int>>>` to match with map's `value_type`.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question -- instead post an Answer saying what you did to solve the problem, and leave the Question as a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple method is to create a structure with all three fields:

```
struct Record
{
  std::string word;
  int         count;
  std::streampos file_position;
};
```

Next is to iterate through the map, creating instances of the above structure, filling them in and appending to the vector:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
for (map<string,p>::const_iterator iter = m.begin();
     iter != m.end();
     ++iter)
{
  Record r;
  r.word = iter->first;
  r.count = iter->second.first;
  r.file_position = iter->second.second;
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

The vector is now filled, sorted order.  The order can be changed by using `std::sort()` and a custom compare function.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat expensive solution that sorts the string list by reference to the map:

```
// Make word list
std::vector<std::string> words;
words.reserve(m.size());
for (const auto & p : m) words.push_back(p.first);

// Sort
std::sort(
    words.begin(), words.end(),
    [&m](const std::string & lhs, const std::string & rhs)
    { return m.find(lhs)->second < m.find(rhs)->second; });
```